# Multiple SSLContext with Webclient from WebFlux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty, sslcontext

I need to call multiple different API's from my application with WebClient.
Let's say, there are two different API's. For these API's I have to use different SSLContexts that built from different certificates.
I create different SSLContexts for them (using different certificates).

As a backend for WebClient I use standard approach - `ReactorClientHttpConnector` with Reactor Netty Http client

SSL can be configured there the following way:

```java
new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext))
);
```

But I'm not sure how to configure multiple different SSLContext (for each API).

Now I see three ways for doing that:

---

## Option 1:

Create two different `ReactorClientHttpConnector` with different HttpClient (`HttpClient.create`) and put there my SSLContexts.

Eventually I'll have two WebClients each based on it's own ReactorClientHttpConnector.
I don't know if this is the valid approach since I suspect I'll have then two different event loop groups in my application

## Option 2:

Maybe I can chain .secure() method and add different SSLContexts like this:

```java
new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext))
        .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext2))
);
```

However, I'm not sure if they will be both applied and not overrided, and if it will work at all.

## Option 3:

Somehow create one SSLContext that contains all the required certificates

---

So, how to handle with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two different `WebClient`s - this is approach 1

> Create two different ReactorClientHttpConnector with different HttpClient (HttpClient.create) and put there my SSLContexts.
> Eventually I'll have two WebClients each based on it's own ReactorClientHttpConnector. I don't know if this is the valid approach since I suspect I'll have then two different event loop groups in my application

The two `WebClient`s will share the event loop group. They will use different event loop groups **ONLY** if you configure them via `runOn` or you use `ReactorResourceFactory`. See more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-resources)